# Magento 'Sort By' - How to make Magento forget which option was selected

Tags: sorting, magento

Something that I have not noticed before is that Magento will remember which option you've selected to 'Sort By' on category list pages. So if you go to a category page, and lets say the default sort is ordered by price, if you change the sort to be ordered by name instead, the page reloads and all is well.

However, if you remove the get variable(s) in the URL and reload the page, it still sorts by name instead of reverting back to price.

I was thinking this was a problem specific to the site I'm working on, as there are some custom things happening with collection building and sorting and such, but I've now checked a handful of other Magento sites (some of which I found at random on the web) and they all do the same thing.

Does anyone know how this is being 'remembered'? Is this stored in user's session? I would think it's part of caching, but this site is still in development and thus caching is disabled.

It's not that big of a deal, but it does seem like a bug.

Comment: There is a question like this (with a more detailed answer) on Magento Stackexchange: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/how-to-make-products-per-page-setting-reset-to-default-on-pageload

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort order parameter is stored in session. See `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::getCurrentOrder` method. You can switch it off by calling `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::disableParamsMemorizing` method or by setting `params_memorize_allowed` in catalog session. I mean `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setParamsMemorizeAllowed(true)`

Comment: This can best be executed in your `local.xml`:

`<reference name="product_list_toolbar"><action method="disableParamsMemorizing" /></reference>`

Comment: I have custom block with custom page for product listing.. I tried to use both ways.. but both are not working for me..
I also have overridden `getToolbarBlock()` function and added `$block->disableParamsMemorizing();` below `if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName))`.. Anything I am missing...?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is adding this in `local.xml`:

```
<!--
 Category default layout
-->
<catalog_category_default translate="label">

  <!-- Disable memorizing toolbar parameters -->
  <reference name="content">
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
      <action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
    </reference>
  </reference>

</catalog_category_default>


<!--
  Category layered navigation layout
-->
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">

  <!-- Disable memorizing toolbar parameters -->
  <reference name="content">
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
      <action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
    </reference>
  </reference>

</catalog_category_layered>
```