# Magento 1.4.1.1 category sort order stored in cookie

Tags: magento

The Magento category sort order seams to be stored in cookies.
Lets say default sort oder is by Name ascending. If a user changes this in descending then all next pages will have this sort order too.

How can i change this so the user sees in the next category the default sort order?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but comes up as the first Google result for "Magento sort by cookie". So, in the spirit of SO, let's answer it!

To begin we must do some investigation, but first we need to know what our assumptions are.

**Assumptions**

- Sort by state is stored in a cookie
- Cookie is updated when the sort by select is changed

**Where to start?**

When in doubt in Magento in a situation like this, start in the frontend where your output is viewable.

If we look in `\app\design\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml`

We see that the following handles the javascript action when the "Sort By" select box is changed.

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/sort_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/sort_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

In particular, we're interested in the `<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">` portion. So what happens when this method is called?

Deeper down the hole we go! `setLocation` is defined in `\js\varien\js.js` around line 30.

```
function setLocation(url){
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

So that's simple enough, it's just your basic Javascript new location directive.

When this `<select>` is changed, we are sent to a new URL *with some parameters*. This is the most probable location of the cookie setting.

Again in particular we are interested in the url parameters `?dir=<asc OR desc>&order=<whatever_metric_you_are_sorting_by>`. Let's go out on a limb and take a guess that the `order` parameter is causing a "setCookie" method or something of the sort to be called.

Where do we find this though? Well that's simple: all Magento actions on a request can be followed from `index.php` to the final frontend rendering, so it MUST happen somewhere along the way! You can track down just about ANY action in Magento using this method.

However, to save you and I some time, we can also assume that cookies probably aren't set *that* often in any given web framework. Running a `grep` on the Magento directory for `('core/cookie')` returns 23 hits in 14 files. That's narrowed it down pretty stinkin' well!

Of the 23 hits, only 4 of them are using the `('core/cookie')->set()` method.
Of the 4 using the `set()` method:

`\app\code\core\Mage\Persistent\Model\Observer\Session.php - line 79`
`\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Helper\Guest.php - line 100`
`\app\code\core\Mage\XmlConnect\controllers\ConfigurationController.php - line 112`
`\app\code\core\Mage\XmlConnect\controllers\Adminhtml\Connect\ConfigController.php - line 101`

Of those 4, only 2 of them are going to be dealing with your end user directly, namely `Session.php`, and `Guest.php`. Since the `Guest.php` is part of the `Sales` module in Magento AND part of the `loadValidOrder()` method, it is quite unlikely that it is dealing with product list sorting. That leaves us with 1 option left, and that is:

`\app\code\core\Mage\Persistent\Model\Observer\Session.php - line 79`

What does inspection of this code tell us?

```
// Set new cookie
if ($sessionModel->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->set(
        Mage_Persistent_Model_Session::COOKIE_NAME,
        $sessionModel->getKey(),
        $persistentLifeTime
    );
}
```

That all the cookie is storing is a session ID for the server! It's almost like this is *standard practice* or something for modern web frameworks! ;). One of our base assumptions was incorrect!

**TL;DR The Answer**

The sort by preference is saved in the Magento server-side session for that client, and recalled when the user returns with the ID stored in the cookie.

To make it so Magento doesn't save this, we must do the following then:

[Magento 'Sort By' - How to make Magento forget which option was selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621273/magento-sort-by-how-to-make-magento-forget-which-option-was-selected)

I figured instead of just linking the answer, I would explain how to get from your line of thinking to the answer, which is much more valuable since now you understand WHY the answer is the correct one. Enjoy and happy coding.

**Update**

Since the SO thread I linked accepted answer doesn't really follow Magento XML protocol, but the comment on the answer *does*, I'll post it here with credit to the Author of the comment:

You need to apply a Layout update with the following xml for the pages you want Magento to "forget" sorting order on:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
</reference>
```

- by SO User [Giel Berkers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471590/giel-berkers)

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can. If the user is trying to improve their experience which only effects them then the cookie is updated and until this cookie expires the sort order will always show as they have selected.

You could clear the cookie on every time the pagination is clicked but this could cause other issue if the user is logged in.

Not only that it would remove and products that may have been added to their basket.

I would suggest to accept the user is responsable for they wish to view the listings, or simply remove the option " sort oder is by Name ascending" for example so they cannot select it.

Comment: But this does not make sense to the user experience.

Comment: May be you need to explain in more detail, but from what i gather if a user wishes to see the search items displayed in a certain way that thats their choice. Again if a Cookie stores it you either have to remove the cookie on page load or dont give the user the option in the first place